# Window touchscreen access to a nib, after using rootViewController in a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Good day.

I cant figure out how to return touchscreen access to a nib, after giving rootViewController to a, well, ViewController, and then doing as follows, to reveal the nib:

At LaunchViewController:

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhoneContent" owner:self options:nil];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//if omitted, screen shows LaunchViewController only
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

"PhoneContent" class has:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
// load our data from a plist file inside our app bundle
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content_iPhone" ofType:@"plist"];
self.contentList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.rootViewController.contentList = self.contentList;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = (UIViewController *)self.rootViewController;
}
```

Additional info:

PhoneContent is an NSObject holding the Nib (.xib)

Revealed Nib is visualised but does not respond to touch gestures.

Comment: what do u mean by touch screen access ?

Comment: @Mr.T: I can visualise the content from PhoneContent, but can't use its elements (button, etc), like if it was frozen, but it is not frozen, because at console other background calculus keep running.